# Can a user be allowed to Create a CiviMail but not Schedule it

Tags: civimail, permissions

Concept is some users can only create Drafts, and then effectively submit them to some higher authority (presumably creates an Activity to notify right people) who has to Review and Schedule the mailing.

Anyone done anything like this yet?

If not, then I guess the bare minimum is a new Permission for 'Create Draft Mailing' which removes the 'Submit' option from the work flow.

Second step would be how to ensure the higher authority gets notified there is a Draft they need to review.

Answer (score 2):

Just had [this](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15854) pointed out to me on IRC - which suggests that some thought was giving to creating 3 levels of permissions:

- Create mailing
- Schedule mailing
- Approve mailing

but looking like it missed the cut in the implementation.

Further documentation at [18400](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18400)